# How to add 'listview rows' from fragment 1 to fragment 2 with SQL?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have several custom list views set up inside each separate fragment. What is the way to save a specific list row from fragment 1 and immediately retrieve it into a dedicated (favorites) fragment? The user should also be able to delete (unfavorite) the list rows that have been populated in the favorites fragment.

And since each list row has a specific onItemClick action associated with them, will this stay consistent when the row is accessed from the favorites fragment?

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the data in one fragment, update the data in your database, and tell the other fragments to reload the data. In order to do that register a BroadcastReciever in all fragments that listens to the action when the database have been updated. Maybe it is faster to do it directly between the fragments, but this way you can garantee the consecvency of the UI and the DB.